# Javascript for a specific wordpress page

Tags: javascript

I have a website that is run with Wordpress.

There is a specific page that I need users to upload a picture, zoom in/out, and crop the picture in a circle to print it out.  All needs to be done from mobile devices.

I have found croppie on Github, and installed all the files.  However, the script is not working.  I think the issue is WP, but have not found any solutions online.

Is there an issue with J/S and wordpress?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Please read this [guide](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and share some code with us.

Comment: sorry...was just trying to see if it's known issue with j/s and WP.  The code is a common one - croppie...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_enqueue_scripts hook to load js file. Once you load the js file successfully, then the issue will not regarding WP.